# How to solve an arbitrary-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can I solve the following equation for $h(z)$, given a particular *n*?
$$z^n (z^n+1)|h'(z)|^n=K$$

Comment: If $const.>0$ and the starting point is, say, $z_0=1$, $$h(1)+\int_1^z\frac{const.}{t\sqrt[n]{t^n+1}}\,dt$$

Comment: Could you please simplify it. I cannot solve this integral :)

Comment: It cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Tnx dear @ G.Sassatelli. How about $$(z^n+1).|h'(z)|^n=const.$$. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting $t = (1+z^n)^{1/n}$, we have:

$$h(z) =C \int\frac{t^{n-2}}{t^n -1}dt$$

for $n=4$, this is:

$$h(z) = C\int \frac{t^2}{t^4 - 1}dt = \frac{C}2 \left[ \int \frac{dt}{t^2 + 1} + \int \frac{dt}{t^2 -1} \right] = \frac{C}2 \left[\arctan t + \frac12 \ln \left| \frac{t-1}{t+1} \right| \right] \\ = \frac{C}2 \left[ \arctan\left( \sqrt[4]{1 + z^4} \right) + \frac12 \ln \left| \frac{\sqrt[4]{1 + z^4} -1}{\sqrt[4]{1 + z^4} + 1} \right| \right]$$

Comment: Tnx @ Ahmed Hussein. How can I solve $$(z^n+1).|h'(z)|^n=const.$$. ?